# php - Symfony2 - Save a ManyToMany with others attributes

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-many, entity, symfony-forms

I have a form with an entity Program, an entity Organization and an other one ProgramOrganization who makes the relation between the first ones.

This entity ProgramOrganization is related with OneToMany/ManyToOne because it contains other fields.

The problem it is the form displays correctly, but when I want to save it in my database, I have this message:

"Found entity of type ...\NomBundle\Entity\Organization on association ...\NomBundle\Entity\Program#programmeOrganisations, but expecting ...\NomBundle\Entity\ProgramOrganization"

I use SensioGeneratorBundle and the doctrine:shema:validate is correct.

On the other hand, if I remove this relation, everything saves correctly.

Here is an extract of my codes: (Attributes Not translated)

**Entity Program :**

```html
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProgrammeOrganisation", mappedBy="programme")
 */
protected $programmeOrganisations;
 
 /**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->programmeOrganisations = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
 
 /**
 * Add programmeOrganisations
 *
 * @param \...\...\Entity\ProgrammeOrganisation $programmeOrganisations
 * @return Programme
 */
public function addProgrammeOrganisation(\...\Entity\ProgrammeOrganisation $programmeOrganisations)
{
    $this->programmeOrganisations[] = $programmeOrganisations;
     
    return $this;
}
 
/**
 * Remove programmeOrganisations
 *
 * @param \...\...\Entity\ProgrammeOrganisation $programmeOrganisations
 */
public function removeProgrammeOrganisation(\...\...\Entity\ProgrammeOrganisation $programmeOrganisations)
{
    $this->programmeOrganisations->removeElement($programmeOrganisations);
}
 
/**
 * Get programmeOrganisations
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getProgrammeOrganisations()
{
    return $this->programmeOrganisations;
}
```

**Entity Organization :**

```html
/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProgrammeOrganisation", mappedBy="organisation")
 */
protected $programmeOrganisations;
 
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->programmeOrganisations = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
 
/**
 * Add programmeOrganisations
 *
 * @param \...\...\Entity\ProgrammeOrganisation $programmeOrganisations
 * @return Organisation
 */
public function addProgrammeOrganisation(\...\...\Entity\ProgrammeOrganisation $programmeOrganisations)
{
    $this->programmeOrganisations[] = $programmeOrganisations;
 
    return $this;
}
 
/**
 * Remove programmeOrganisations
 *
 * @param \...\...\Entity\ProgrammeOrganisation $programmeOrganisations
 */
public function removeProgrammeOrganisation(\...\...\Entity\ProgrammeOrganisation $programmeOrganisations)
{
    $this->programmeOrganisations->removeElement($programmeOrganisations);
}
 
/**
 * Get programmeOrganisations
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getProgrammeOrganisations()
{
    return $this->programmeOrganisations;
}
```

**Entity ProgramOrganization :**

```html
class ProgrammeOrganisation
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Programme", inversedBy="programmeOrganisations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="programme_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $programme;
 
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Organisation", inversedBy="programmeOrganisations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="organisation_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $organisation;
 
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ContributionType")
     */
    private $contributionType;
 
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date;
 
}
```

**ProgramType**

```html
->add('programmeOrganisations' , 'entity' , array(
                      'class'    => 'NomBundle:Organisation' ,
                      'label' => 'Organisations list',
                      'property' => 'label' ,
                      'expanded' => false ,
                      'multiple' => true ,
                       
                    ))
```

**ProgramController**

```html
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Programme();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
 
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
 
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('programme_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }
 
        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }
 
    /**
     * Creates a form to create a Programme entity.
     *
     * @param Programme $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(Programme $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new ProgrammeType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('programme_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));
 
        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));
 
        return $form;
    }
 
    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Programme entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="programme_new")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Programme();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
 
        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is here, i don't see a link between your Program and Organization but your formtype says that i want a form linked with Organization entity on $ProgrammeOrganizations variable which is declared as ProgrammeOrganization entity not Organization.

```
 ->add('programmeOrganisations' , 'entity' , array(
                  'class'    => 'NomBundle:ProgrammeOrganisation ' ,
                  'label' => 'Organisations list',
                  'property' => 'label' ,
                  'expanded' => false ,
                  'multiple' => true ,

                ))
```

Should do it. Maybe there is other error that i didn't noticed

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73948/discussion-on-answer-by-nawfal-serrar-php-symfony2-save-a-manytomany-with-ot).